# php5 cli: no output

Tags: php

i've got a php script that runs on the command line. To improve it's performance, i would like to completely suppress it's output.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure about performance but you can use

```
php -q myscript.php > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to call [ob_start()](http://php.net/ob_start) to turn on output buffering, and periodically call [ob_clean()](http://php.net/ob_clean) if you really don't want the output (or use a dummy ob_start() callback which does nothing).

Not sure how much of a performance gain this would be, as internally, PHP is still processing the output, except it goes into a buffer rather than to stdout.

If you've got a lot of diagnostic output you want to prevent, than it might be more effective to refactor your code to allow that to be suppressed by an application option.

Comment: That's why I proposed dummy ob_esity that devours all output before it hits the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

```
fclose(STDOUT);
```

This will work cross platform as the first line in the PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ob_esity($b) { return ''; }
ob_start('ob_esity');
```

Comment: Neither I do. Well, maybe a bit. It sure will not buffer anything. I'd go for redirecting output myself, but that wouldn't comply with `php` tag ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Using **> /dev/null** is not enough?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the script replace all `echo` with `//echo`. Perfect performance increase, but you will need to check multi-line echo statements.